# Angular Material md-container-input date format issue with different browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angular-material

I'm having an issue using the angular material library with the md-input-container for dates.  In Chrome and Edge the input gets styled with a nice calendar dropdown and mask, and wants MM/dd/yyyy format but in Firefox and IE I get no controls and it is yyyy-MM-dd format.

Is there a way around this?  I don't see any attributes to handle this.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input